# TLP (Power saving) - Will configuration remain after uninstall?

Tags: power-management, battery, tlp

As the title says: will selected configuration remain after TLP uninstallation? For example, if I configure TLP to disable USB ports in AC and Battery modes and then I uninstall TLP, will USB ports still be disabled? If not, why? I mean, doesn't TLP modify system configuration files to achieve the desired energy configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, TLP does not modify system files. After uninstall all settings are gone (after a system restart).

Btw: there is no TLP setting to "disable USB ports"